# Create a stored procedure with parameters as arrayOfJson objects to insert each object properties as individual columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

I have to insert values `[{name:'ravi',age;20},{name:'kumar',age;22}]`. The stored procedure should take this array as input and store this as individual columns like below.

Table

```
name - age
ravi   20
age    22
```

Procedure to insert a json object:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertJson(jsonObjects ARRAY[]) 
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MyTable 
    VALUES (jsonObjects)
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertJson(obj JSONB)
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
      INSERT INTO test2 (name, "age")
      SELECT arr.row ->> 'name', (arr.row ->> 'age')::numeric FROM (SELECT jsonb_array_elements(obj) as row) as arr;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```